# How do I return just the fields from a query?

Tags: elasticsearch

If I run a search query, I want to be able to select just the distinct fields from the hits/sources. To be clear, I don't want to limit the fields that are returned, I want to select the available fields as a list. Is this possible?

For example, if I ran a typical search and there are three results each with different fields:

`R1
 "Field1": "foo"
 "Field2": "bar"
R2
 "Field2": "bara"
R3
 "Field1": "fooa"
 "Field3": "baz"`

The result would be `["Field1", "Field2", "Field3"]`

Comment: It is possible to limit fields in response using _source filter. As far as I understand, you want to get values of those fields as primitive list/array, don't you?

Comment: @antonbormotov I don't actually want the values, just the field names